# SAS split long character variable into 2 variables

Tags: sas

I have a messy dataset whic contains lastnames, firstnames, addresses (in that order) in one variable, while I would need this to be 2 different ones (names and address).
I tried

```
 data commainvest (keep=appln_id person_id person_name lastname firstnames newname address);
 set commainvest;
 lastname=scan(person_name,1,',') ;
 firstnames=scan(person_name,2,',') ;
 newname=catx(', ',lastname,firstnames) ;
 address=substr(person_name,1,length(person_name)-length(newname)) ;
 run;
```

and others such as

```
   address= substr(person_name,-1,length(person_name)-length(newname)) ;
```

or

```
   address= scan(person_name,3,length(person_name)) ;
```

but it always cuts the address part incorrectly or leaves all the info in the last column.
There is also actually no need to cut last and firstnames, but I could find a way to leave them together from the start. My data is separated by commas between them.
I appreciate your help
Thanks
Anna

Comment: can you show an example of your data?

Comment: It would be much easier to see what is going on if I could see a line of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are getting truncated data due to the default length of the new `address` variable.

```
data commainvest (keep=appln_id person_id person_name lastname firstnames newname address);
  set commainvest;
  lastname=scan(person_name,1,',') ;
  firstnames=scan(person_name,2,',') ;
  newname=catx(', ',lastname,firstnames) ;
  length address $1000;
  address=substr(person_name,length(newname),length(person_name)-length(newname)) ;
run;
```

Try the above (with length statement).  Your code otherwise looks fine!

Comment: no, that's not it (for example if I leave as length " length(person_name)", then it's the whole line incl. the names). I can not make it understand that only what is not in last/firstname should be in address. If I put "length(person_name)-length(newname)", then it cuts it from the end and not from the beginning.

Comment: apologies yes, the `substr` should not start from the first position, answer updated!